# how to find the most recommended category in 2016

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to make a request that answers the following question: write the SQL statement that displays one of the most requested movie categories in the year 2016 ?

Here is the diagram

[image: here is the link of the diagram]

Comment: Please not post pictures, post tables structure, sample data and desired result as text [mre]

Comment: Not sure Stack Overflow is here to help you do your homework. However, avoid pictures, use text / ASCII art or DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework question:

You need to `JOIN` the `FILM` table to the `COPIE` table to the `LOCATION` table using their primary and foreign key relationships.

You need to know for each `CATEGORIE` of `FILM` how many times it was rented/streamed/borrowed and that would be done by aggregation and a `GROUP BY` clause.

Then you need to filter the result set to only return values `WHERE` they were rented/streamed/borrowed before the end of 2016 and returned after the start of 2016 (so that some period of their borrowing should overlap some days in 2016).

Then you need to `COUNT` the `LOCATION` for each `CATEGORIE`.

Finally, you need to `ORDER` the result set by that `COUNT` in `DESC`ending order and (assuming you are using Oracle 12 or later) can `FETCH` the `FIRST ROW ONLY`.

Comment: when i do this it gives me an error in the FETCH :

`
SELECT categorie, COUNT(categorie) AS "value_occurrence"

FROM film INNER JOIN copie ON film.id_film = copie.id_film
    INNER JOIN location ON copie.id_copie = location.id_copie

WHERE date_loc BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-2016','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31-12-2016','DD/MM/YYYY')

  AND date_retour BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-2016','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31-12-2016','DD/MM/YYYY')

GROUP BY categorie

ORDER BY "value_occurrence" DESC

FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;`